# How to write Autodesk.Viewing.Extensions with webpack and react?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, autodesk-forge

I was write code within view3D v2.11, React, ES6 and webpack. But I don't know how to write `Autodesk.Viewing.Extensions` within webpack and React. Can anyone show me some examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using webpack to write a viewer extension is no different than using webpack to write any other js application. Take a look at my extensions library repo, each extension is bundled into a separate .js or .min.js whether you build the project in dev or prod: [library-javascript-viewer-extensions](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/library-javascript-viewer-extensions).

This is designed this way so each extension can be loaded dynamically independently, however if you build an entire application around the viewer, you may simply include the code for each extension along with the rest of the app and generate a single webpack bundle.

This React project contains multiple viewer extensions (some are extracted from the library mentioned above) and is bundling extensions code along with the rest of the app: [forge-rcdb](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-rcdb.nodejs).

As far as React and the viewer are concerned, it's not very relevant because the viewer is a 3D component which is created dynamically, all WebGL canvas and viewer 2D elements are being generated after your app loads a model, whereas React lets you declare 2D components when the app is starting. I was playing a bit with injecting dynamically React components to the viewer div, you can take a look in that same project [here](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-rcdb.nodejs/blob/master/src/client/components/Viewer/Viewer.js#L103):

```
this.viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D(this.viewerContainer)

// Experimental !
// This this to render dynamic components
// inserted after the viewer div has been created

const reactViewerNode = document.createElement('div')

this.viewer.container.appendChild(reactViewerNode)

this.viewer.react = {
    node: reactViewerNode,
    components: [],
    addComponent: (component) => {

      this.viewer.react.components.push(component)
    },
    render: (props) => {

      ReactDOM.render(
        <div>
        {
          React.Children.map(
            this.viewer.react.components,
            (child) => React.cloneElement(child, props))
          }
        </div>,
        reactViewerNode)
    }
  }
```

I then render those dynamic components by overriding [componentDidUpdate](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-rcdb.nodejs/blob/master/src/client/components/Viewer/Viewer.js#L155):

```
componentDidUpdate () {

 if (this.viewer && this.viewer.react) {

   if(this.viewer.react.components.length) {

    this.viewer.react.render(this.props)
   }
 }
}
```

and [there](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-rcdb.nodejs/blob/master/src/client/routes/Viewer/components/ViewerView.js#L295) is an example of use:

```
viewer.react.addComponent(
    <DBDropdown key="test" className="react-div">
    </DBDropdown>
)
```

I actually haven't implemented any feature using that in the [live version](https://forge-rcdb.autodesk.io/) of the app, but it should give you an idea.

Hope that helps.